# Getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Im trying to parse a website and save its contents to CSV file but on line

```
brand = make_rating_sp[0].img["title"].title()
```

I get the typescript error

```
for container in containers:
   make_rating_sp = container.div.select("a")

   brand = make_rating_sp[0].img["title"].title()

   product_name = container.div.select("a")[2].text

   shipping = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})[0].text.strip().replace("$", 
   "").replace(" Shipping", "")
   print("brand: " + brand + "\n")
   print("product_name: " + product_name + "\n")
   print("shipping: " + shipping + "\n")
   f.write(brand + ", " + product_name.replace(",", "|") + ", " + shipping + "\n")
```

Comment: `make_rating_sp` is an empty collection.

Comment: print make_rating_sp, it has nothing (None) and so you can't [0].img["title"] whatever on it because there's nothing in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely seeing `IndexError: list index out of range`, but you may also encounter problems if the `make_rating_sp` list contains elements, but the specific `a` tag at the specified index does not contain an `img` tag.

Try adding something like:

```
   brand = ""
   try:
       brand = make_rating_sp[0].img["title"].title()
   except:
       pass
```

Often in Python you will want to catch specific [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), but in this instance a generic solution is probably sufficient.